# SharePoint 2010 - Create related hierarchical fields from external source

Tags: 2010, column, custom, bcs, custom-field-types

Is there a way to create two related columns as a custom field type in SharePoint? For example, can you develop a custom field type named CustomerOrder that consists of two related lookup columns Customer (dropdown lookup with validation from external source) and Orders (the orders lookup would only display orders for the selected customer). The Customer and Customer Order tables are external to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear whether you are wanting to create a view or a historical list, but this is a system for creating a custom view based on two external lists.  It will require the use of SharePoint Designer.

Either way this might help:

[How to Link Two Lists](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194252/How-to-Link-Two-Lists-and-Create-a-Combined-Ciew-i)

Comment: I am not looking to create a view or historical list. I am looking to add two columns (to any list) that are populated from an external source (SQL Server). The built-in External Content Types allow you to create a single field from an external source. However, you cannot create relationships among two External Content Type columns (as far as I know). I was wondering if there is a way to do it through custom development or not.

Comment: There is, but again SharePoint Designer has some of this functionality already, you would just need to manipulate the process to your needs.  Here I have a link from the MSDN and it actually uses customer and customer order as an example.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394632(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I guess I am not being clear about what I am trying to accomplish. I want to create a custom list. In that custom list, I want an external data column Customer that pulls from a SQL Server table. I then want to add another column to the custom list - Customer Order, that will filter down to the orders particular to the selected Customer.